# How to solve low disk space on /boot/ in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, boot, centos, centos-7

I am getting Low Disk Space on `/boot/` in CentOS 7. I got this error since I recently did `yum update`.

The `df` command shows 100% usage on boot folder.

Following are the snapshots.

[image: Low Disk Space on "boot" error]

[image: disk usage report]

Comment: I don't understand, is superuser a group inside stack overflow ?

Comment: @spandanpradhan Can you show us the output of `ls -l /boot` ?

Comment: @pun: following is the output of command *ls -l /boot* [ls -l /boot output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mhOMU.png)

Comment: @spandanpradhan Consider marking the current top-voted answer as a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As answered by [@strandraeber](https://superuser.com/a/1100814/270195) above your `/boot/` is full due to old kernels

One way to fix this would be deleting old kernels.

You can do that by installing [yum-utils](https://blog.bartbania.com/linux-2/remove-old-kernels-centos/) and running command as shown

`package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1`

*This will delete all old kernels except for latest one. You can play with the numbers too.*

Another option for you is to resize boot partition.

**Edit:** Adding another point which I learned from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/82230/270195)
 that is to relocate your `/boot/` partition as well.

Comment: Keep at least two kernels. Chances are your latest kernel wasn't successfully installed due to lack of space.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably old and unused kernel images residing in /boot. According to this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83420/176600 you can remove them with `yum autoremove`.